# Trying to remove session array from array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session

Im trying to remove a session['cart_items] array from a multi array and I can't seem to get the delete part to work.

I'm getting the id through: $_POST['product] however I've tried the following and getting a bit stuck:

```
$temp = array_flip($_SESSION['cart_items']);    
unset($_SESSION['cart_items'][$temp[$_POST['product']]]);
```

I've also tried:

```
unset($_SESSION['cart_items'][$key]);
```

My output is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 407
                [item_name] => Am I Bothered? About Homophobia
                [item_qty] => 22
            )

    )

)
```

An help would be great

Multiple array result:

```
array(1) {
  ["cart_items"]=>
array(2) {
[1]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["item_id"]=>
    string(3) "407"
    ["item_name"]=>
    string(31) "Am I Bothered? About Homophobia"
    ["item_qty"]=>
    string(2) "50"
  }
}
[2]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["item_id"]=>
    string(4) "1131"
    ["item_name"]=>
    string(50) "10 Ways A Condom Can’t Protect You – Postcards"
    ["item_qty"]=>
    string(2) "14"
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['cart_items'][$key] = ""` ?

Comment: $key=array_search($_POST['product'],$_SESSION['cart_items']);

Comment: what is the $key value? is it same array index?

Comment: I mean use that instead of `unset()`

Comment: Yes trying to delete the array where item_id = $_POST['product']

Comment: @michael - the array will have multiple products - would your solution still work?

Comment: Are you getting correct key? Because cart_items is two dimensional array but you are searching item id.

Comment: Yes - the key im getting is 407 (the item_id i'm trying to remove).

Comment: If $key is 407, you are trying to unset $_SESSION['cart_items'][407] ?

Comment: @jamper, I don't have your code, but my answer is worth at try.. test it out

Comment: $_SESSION['cart_items'] is two dimensional array. I am assuming you are getting correct $key.  So if you want to remove item =  407 which is located at $_SESSION['cart_items'][0][0], so you will have to remove $_SESSION['cart_items'][0][$key] NOT $_SESSION['cart_items'][$key]

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<sizeof($_SESSION['cart_items'][0]);i++){
    if($_SESSION['cart_items'][0][i]['item_id'] == $key);
        unset($_SESSION['cart_items'][0][i]['item_id']);
}
```

Comment: This is almost working - apart from I want to remove the entire array where the item_id = $key, I tried to remove the ['item_id'] from unset() but it didn't work. Almost there ;)

Comment: for(i=0;i<sizeof($_SESSION['cart_items'][0]);i++){
    if($_SESSION['cart_items'][0][i]['item_id'] == $key);
        unset($_SESSION['cart_items'][0][i]);
}

Use this one.

Comment: Very unfortunate that I was to indicating this issue in my comments. Look at my comments

Comment: This works for single items in the cart - when there are multiples it fails to remove it from the session.

Comment: Show me your multiple array, then I will let you know.

Comment: Have added the multi array result